# Cannot add a post dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular and trying to do an exercise where I add dynamic posts to a webpage, while interacting with API.

[The front page looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYurZ.png)

The form needs to be filled out and then the content is added below. Everything works fine and the content is being added, but in order for it to get updated I have to refresh the page while my goal is to add it dynamically. In order to do it I tried using an event emitter. Below is the code:

this is the component for the form (post-form.component.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Post } from 'src/app/interfaces';
import { PostService } from 'src/app/services/post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-form',
  templateUrl: './post-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-form.component.css']
})
export class PostFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() addPostEvent: EventEmitter<Post> = new EventEmitter();
  post: Post = {
    title: '',
    body: ''
  };
 
  loading:boolean=false;
  constructor(private postService:PostService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    
    this.loading = true;
    this.postService.writePost(this.post).subscribe(post => {
      this.addPostEvent.emit(post);
      this.post = {
        title: '',
        body: ''
      };
      this.loading = false;
      
    })
  }
}
```

(post-feed.component.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../../interfaces';
import { PostService } from 'src/app/services/post.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-feed',
  templateUrl: './post-feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-feed.component.css']
})
export class PostFeedComponent implements OnInit {
 posts: Post[];

  constructor(private postService:PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.posts=posts;
    })
  }
    
  onPostAdded(newPost: Post) {
    this.posts.unshift(newPost);
  }
    
}
```

post-form.component.html:

```
<form
    *ngIf="!loading"
    
    #postForm="ngForm"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(postForm)"
    style="margin:50px"
    >

    <div class="input-field">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text"
        class="validate"
        name="title"
        [(ngModel)]="post.title"
        required
        >
        <span class="helper-text" data-error="Field must not be empty"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <input type="text"
        class="validate"
        name="body"
        [(ngModel)]="post.body"
        required
        >
        <span class="helper-text" data-error="Field must not be empty"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit"
    class="waves-effect waves-light btn" [disabled]="!postForm.valid"
    >Add</button>
</form>

<div class="progress" *ngIf="loading">
    <div class="interminate">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

post-feed.component.html:

```
<br><br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s6">
        <app-post-form>
            (addPostEvent)="onPostAdded($event)"
        </app-post-form>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col s6" *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                <p class="card-title">
                    {{ post.title }}
                </p>
                <p class="timestamp">
                    {{ post.createdAt | date }}
                </p>
                <p> {{ post.body }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a href="#">Edit</a>
                <a href="#">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

post.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post } from '../interfaces';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService {

  url: string = 'https://ndb99xkpdk.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev';

  options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  }
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts():Observable<Post[]> { 
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(`${this.url}/posts`)
  }

 writePost(post: Post): Observable<Post> {
    if (post.id) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return this.http.post<Post>(`${this.url}/post`, post, this.options);
    }
  }

}
```

interface.ts:

```
export interface Post {
    id?:string;
    createdAt?:string;
    userId?:string;
    title:string;
    body:string;

}
```

There are no errors in the console. What am I doing wrong?
Bless your heart!

Answer (score 0):

in `post-feed.component.html:`, replace it:

```
<app-post-form>
    (addPostEvent)="onPostAdded($event)"
</app-post-form>
```

with:

```
<app-post-form (addPostEvent)="onPostAdded($event)">
</app-post-form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    this.postService.writePost(this.post).subscribe(post => {
      this.addPostEvent.emit(post);
```

This emits the response of your backend server `${this.url}/post`. I guess your server does not return the posted contents.

Try modifing `this.addPostEvent.emit(post);` to `this.addPostEvent.emit(this.post);`